# Google Places API - Busca com várias keywords utilizando google places api com javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Estou com problema para encontrar uma forma de buscar por mais de uma palavra chave ao mesmo tempo, não encontrei nada na documentação do google sobre isso. Preciso buscar por sanduíches, mas em São Paulo, principalmente no interior, eles chamam sanduíches por lanches, por exemplo. Então quando uso a keyword "sanduiches" ou "sanduicheria" ele não retorna as "lanchonetes".

Já tentei de algumas maneiras, mas ainda não tive sucesso:

keyword: 'lanchonete|sanduiche|hamburguer|hot-dog'
keyword: 'lanchonete+sanduiche+hamburguer+hot-dog'
keyword: 'lanchonete,sanduiche,hamburguer,hot-dog'
keyword: 'lanchonete sanduiche hamburguer hot-dog'

Estou utilizando o "nearbySearch".

```js
this.request = {
  location: position,
  radius: '5000',
  keyword: 'lanchonete|sanduiche|hamburguer|hot-dog',
  type: 'food'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com o [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71381034) parece que é *virgulas* em vez de *pipes*

No entanto, depois de bater 50x contra um "invalid query" descobri que se... mudares de `keyword` para `keywords` (plural) isso funciona:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522%2C151.1957362&radius=1000&keywords=food|lodging&key=A_TUA_KEY_AQUI

Comment: utilizando keywords, não filtrou nada.  No navegador funcionou, mas na API não.

Comment: Utilizando vírgulas, ele só me traz um resultado.